# Why my uploaded file to FTP automatically became 0 bytes?

Tags: ftp, data-recovery, webserver, data-loss-prevention

i had uploaded a file to sever and file auto translate to 0 bytes. Server space was 100% full at the time of upload. i did my all work in live so now i have no backup. Already tried notepad++ back-up but not working.
How can get back my lot code ?
How can i get back my lost file?

Comment: You can't. The server should've told you it can't store the file but as it didn't your data is lost.

Comment: @Seth: you are right.  The only option is to get the auto-save copy, if they exist at the local computer you were developing from.

Comment: @tukan is there any other way? because i had worked live.

Comment: @user8527573: Well that will depend on your configuration of Notepad++.  where does it store your backups?

Comment: @tukan had check NP++ but got nothing.
C:\Users\OM\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup

Comment: are you sure that is the correct profile?  This path is a roaming profile.  Please check all the profiles at the computer for the backup files - search for the correct suffix *.bak maybe?

Comment: Your question's title is asking something different from what the content of the question asks. I suggest editing one or the other so they ask the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by making space in server. My sever space capacity exceeded and i was not aware about it when i was uploading files. Deleted unnecessary files and issue automatically solved.